# minify AND concatenate jqGrid locale files?

Tags: jqgrid, internationalization, locale, minify

Has anyone successfully tried minifying AND concatenating all the jqGrid locale files so that they could be loaded in one HTTP request and cached in the browser?

It is a simple task to minify each file separately, but the current jqGrid i18n model requires dynamically loading the correct script file (e.g. `'../i18n/grid.locale-XX.min.js'`) based on the user's locale.  This is because the resource files simply extend the $.jgrid object without even knowing what their own locale is.  Including more than one in a download would simply apply the last one to be loaded and executed.

I would prefer to have all those static locale objects available to the client/browser at once, and then programmatically apply one via the grid options (or perhaps via a jqGrid method).  This seems to be a more common pattern for client side localization, e.g. the jQuery UI Datepicker, Globalize (fka jquery-global), Moment.js and others.

So has anyone successfully done this, or should this be a feature request/contribution to the jqGrid project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would examine [my old feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/#p22314) you will find the most information which you need. [The first](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization.htm) and [the second](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) demos uses jqGrid 3.8.2. The same idea will work in the current jqGrid version too. It will be event easier implemented. In the second demo I used additionally dynamic choice of the language based on the language of the web browsers. The code could be a little improved, but in general I still like the approach.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg.  I searched but didn't find that forum post.  I have my own system to detect the user's locale and supply translated column names, but your idea to add a $.jgrid.regional property is what I was looking for.  I still think this would be a great feature to have built in to the grid instead of altering every locale file.  Maybe this will be my first pull request!

Comment: @aponzani: You are welcome! It would be good if you or other users would also suggest such kind of features.